# Can Mobile Vision API detect Chinese, Japanese and Korean?

Tags: android, mobile, ocr, android-vision

Is it possible for Mobile Vision API to detect Chinese, Japanese and Korean?
If not, is there any way to detect these language in Android?

Comment: try with google translate API.

Comment: Did Google Translate API support OCR?

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Vision API provides support for a much larger set of languages (i.e. Chinese) from an OCR standpoint:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages

Comment: You should probably mention that switching to a service from a library will also mean adding character limitations and possible fees.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect Chinese, Japanese and Korean Tesseract but you will not get 100% result.

Tutorial Link :

http://imperialsoup.com/2016/04/29/simple-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract-tutorial/

---

other Language Data files :

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

---

Sample Links:

https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

https://github.com/imperialsoup/SimpleTesseractExample

Comment: Thanks. I used this before. It takes 3s to detect English but 30s to detect Chinese and Korean. Do you know why?

Comment: I have never try for other then English, but if you will provide grayscale Image then may it will take less time.

Comment: How can I improve Korean??? Is there no way to improve that by myself? Just do you need to use the provider's file?

Comment: @ChanjungKim... For better result and fast processing now you can use google vision API and it also supports the Korean language. check this link: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages and try the API : https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Comment: Thanks. But Google Vision is not free of charge. :(

Comment: @ChanjungKim   Yes, I have checked same for you. So the best option is to go with this link with Korean language pack(trained data). https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/kor.traineddata or https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/kor_vert.traineddata, You need to take very clear, zoom and grayscale image so will process faster than previous (do some image processing by your self).

Comment: @Janak A `very clear, zoom and grayscale image` is not practical for any sort of application outside of a proof of concept.

Comment: @AbandonedCart You are right very clear, zoom and the grayscale image is not practical for any sort of application. But you will provide some image processing functionality in which a user can zoom the image and do default grayscale. So users can get the best result.

Comment: @Janak Are you demanding I provide something with the same limitations or did you intend to demand I provide something with less limitations? I should have warned you that I didn't point out your flaws without considering the argument "but what else is there?" I use https://ocr.space/OCRAPI with full-color and somewhat blurry images and have had nothing but excellent results. The caveat is that you ship the image off to a server in real time, but it is worth it to not cripple the experience.